# Garbage collection and asynchronous calls / Future objects

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is a sample code that utilizes the Future interface to make an asynchronous call. I need some clarification about the get() method.

```
Future<String> future = getAsyncString();
//do something ...
String msg = "";
if (validation)
    return;
else
    msg = future.get();
//do something else...
return;
```

The future variable is initialized in a method , so the variable will be soon cleared by the GC after the method's execution as it is no longer used.
So in case that the code enters the if statement , what will be the state of the JVM? How is the JVM going to handle the wrapped result in case that noone is  going to read it back? Does it affect the Thread Pool , or the thread Executor?

Comment: Variables are not cleared by the GC. The GC cleans up objects that are not referred to anymore by any variable. Note that a variable is not an object; a variable is a *reference* to an object.

Comment: well yes , the code suggests that the future instance will be only used inside the method

Comment: Why are you validating after `getAsyncString()` and not before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is the JVM going to handle the wrapped result in case that noone is going to read it back?

If nobody(I mean any program) is going to read it back then GC will take care of it during garbage collection. But that does not mean `getAsyncString()` will not be executed completely, instead it will complete normally as a normal method completes.

Comment: well this is the answer that i want to confirm , how can we confirm it? shall i check the mem space at run time?

Comment: What do you want to confirm, that is it garbage collected or the executing is complete?

Comment: no it will be executed for sure , as the method is called, the question is what will happen to the wrapped result , in case that the code never reaches the future.get()? will it create a memory leak or whatever?

Comment: No it will not create memory leak, as execution is handled by executor, so even if you does not call a get method, executor will make sure that your method is executed. And if future object is not referred from somewhere else it will be taken care by GC, the same way normal variable is taken care.

Comment: ok that's what i wanted to confirm, because i couldn't find it in any oracle / java documentation, thank you  for your help and your time

Comment: @AntJavaDev, this is what I pointed out in my third paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

> How is the JVM going to handle the wrapped result in case that noone is going to read it back?

Presumably you got the `Future` object from an `Executor`. For this executor to be able to set the result in the `Future`, it holds a reference to the `Future`. In other words, just because the method local reference to the object disappears as the call stack is popped, doesn't mean that the `Future` object (which is on the heap) is automatically eligible for garbage collection.

The async call is not cancelled or anything like that. The executor will perform the call, fill in the result, and presumably drop it's reference to the `Future` object. At *this* point the object becomes unreachable and eligible for garbage collection.

If you're certain that *your* code doesn't keep a reference to the `Future` object (i.e. leaking it in the `// do something...` part) then you can be sure that the `Future` object is (eventually) collected by the GC. (The executor doesn't have any subtle memory leaks here.)

> [...] so the variable will be soon cleared by the GC.

To be precise, the variable will be discarded as the call stack is popped. This will eventually cause the `Future` *object* to be unreachable and eligible for garbage collection. The object will however typically not be garbage collected *immediately* as the method returns.

Comment: so you suggest that after the method's execution , even if i haven't call the future.get() , the reference to the wrapped result will still be there , as the thread executor holds the variable?

Comment: @AntJavaDev The method the future is executing wont be interrupted. It will complete, at which point the Executor will release its reference and the Future object will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @Quirliom, note that the method for which the `Future` should capture the result, may not have been called yet. (Think for instance of a thread pool with 1 thread and many tasks in the queue.)

Comment: so it will be eligible for garbage collection even if the future.get() method never gets called?

Comment: @AntJavaDev, yes, but presumably not until the underlying async call has been executed (because before then, the executor will keep a reference to the `Future` so it knows where to place the result).

Answer (score 1):

I guess. Scheduled future will have some internal references from threadpools queues until task completion. So it cant be collected by gc before task is complete.

May be there is exists additional abstraction level between future and executor and future can be collected. But im sure that if task submitted it will be runned. No matter, was pointer to future saved or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have guarantee that the object will not be GCed while you are in scope in which reference to it is defined, or there is reference to the object somewhere in code.

This applies to all Objects, and Future makes no difference here.

So, once your method ends, and its call stack is cleared, at some point in the future your object will be eligible for Garbage collection, but certainly not before reference to it exists on the method's call stack.